# Do we use 'do' or 'does' when 'and' is uniting two different nouns?

Tags: nouns

In the following sentence should we use 'do' or 'does'? Why?

> As well as this, America’s foreign policy and geopolitical strategies ****does**** not seek to minimise China’s influence in the country, but to pursue its own alliances with countries like Israel or the Gulf countries.

I would say it's 'do' because 'and' unites both nouns ('policy' and 'strategies') but I rather double-check with your guys!

Comment: Juxtaposing singular "policy" and plural "strategies" sounds weird to me, although I admit that it may be technically correct (we have one overarching foreign policy and implement it through numerous strategies).

Comment: @Barmar: I agree; if you're going to put them together as a unit, don't end with the plural right before a singular verb.  Poor editing.

Comment: Please cite the source of your quote.

Answer (score 1):

Turning Edwin Ashworth's comment into an answer for posterity:

> Using notional concord, one needs to look at the composite nature vs individual element implication of the coordination. Thus 'Bacon and eggs does appear on the menu' but 'Bacon and eggs do both appear to be becoming harder to find on supermarket shelves'. Here, I'd say the elements are separate enough to fully justify 'do' (and the juxtaposition 'strategies does' sounds off. Whereas 'bacon and eggs' is almost hyphenated.)

Comment: So why not use a 'Community wiki', as is customary?  The reason I didn't give the answer as an 'answer' is that I consider it close enough to many other questions on notional agreement with coordinated NPs as to constitute a duplicate.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth alphabet is a relatively new user, he might not know how to do that yet.

Comment: @fev If we have a policy requiring the use of community wikis, I will follow it. However, posting answers as comments is strongly frowned upon by the mods, so in the absence of such a rule I don't consider it inappropriate to repost things.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth If it was a duplicate, why not vote to close it accordingly? If it wasn't a duplicate, why not answer it?

Comment: Delete and re-post as a c-w, and I'll reply. It's a simple click when submitting an answer.

Comment: @alphabet It is just curtesy to post it as a Community Wiki so as not to receive reputation that is actually due to the author of the comment. It's not really a rule, just common sense. But of course you can do as you please.